# how to join two tables in sql and showing the results event A then all attendees, Event B and showing all the attendees, etc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, join

Good Afternoon All,

I am creating an admin page that shows a list of events and those who volunteered to help.  I have one table for events and another for those who are volunteer.

I stored the eventID into the volunteer's table and am able to join them, but when i join them I get a new row for each volunteer which also shows the event name again.

I would like to display the event name and underneath the event name show the volunteers.

ex.

```
event A
  Volunteer 1
  volunteer 2
  volunteer 3

event B
  Volunteer 1
  volunteer 2
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public string volunteers(){

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT* FROM fundraiser_youth
                                        LEFT JOIN
                                        fundrasier_helpers ON fundraiser_youth.id = fundrasier_helpers.eventID 
                                        ORDER BY reportTime;", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DateTime reportTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1]);
            DateTime gateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[2]);
            DateTime gameTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[3]);


            VOLUNTEER.Append("<div class='col-md-4'>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<div class='well well-lg'>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<form action='register/default.aspx' method='POST'>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<h4>" + reportTime.DayOfWeek + " " + reportTime.Month + "/" + reportTime.Day + "/" + reportTime.Year + "</h4>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<h5>" + reader[4].ToString() + " " + reader[7].ToString() + " " + reportTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "</h5>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<ul>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<li>" + reader[10].ToString() + " " + reader[11].ToString() + "</li>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("</ul>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<input type=hidden name='id' value='" + reader[8].ToString() + "' />");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("<span style='text-align:right; margin-top:20px;'><input type='submit' value='Register' class='btn btn-info' /></span>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("</form>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("</div>");
            VOLUNTEER.Append("</div>");
        }
        return VOLUNTEER.ToString();
    }
    return "no info provided";
}
```

Comment: database engine please

Comment: normally you would have volunteerMaster, EventMaster and VolunteerEvents Tables

Comment: Not related to your issue, but I would *strongly* recommend not using numerical indexes for your `reader` object.  It makes the code *extremely* difficult to follow/maintain and is *very* prone to breaking.  You should use `reader["ColumnName"]` instead.  It's *much* clearer on the intent.  (On the same note, you should really not be using `SELECT *` for the same reason.  List out exactly which columns you need.)

Comment: May be a union so you have two datasets: "Select * from fundraiser_youth Union
select * from  fundrasier_helpers where eventID in (Select id from fundraiser_youth))

Comment: @Siyual - Personally, I think `select *` is the bigger bad habit. Column names are nice and readable, but a change to the name of a database column requires a change to the string in code, while the same change when using indexes (and an explicitly-defined column list in the select statement) would run just fine. To be fair, name-based column access is more tolerant of a change to the order of the select list; if you used SPs or queries designed to return the same column list, but one has two columns transposed, the name-based reader access wouldn't bat an eye. Depends on the reason to change.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the recommendations on clean up the code, I am going to update this and start doing it the way you suggested.

Comment: When using the column names in the reader how do I differentiate table 1 id from table 2 id using the reader?

Comment: You can use column aliases: `select fundraiser_youth.id as "eventId", fundraiser_helpers.id as "helperId", ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up fixing my problem.  May not be best option but it works, Thanks for everyone's input and in the production code I replaced the select * with the columns.  I made a new function called (loadHelpers) and pass the id of the current Event to it.  This function pulls all the volunteers who signed up to help.

```
 public string volunteers()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM fundraiser_youth WHERE reportTime >='" + DateTime.Now + "' ORDER BY reportTime" , con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime reportTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["reportTime"]);
                DateTime gateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["gateTime"]);
                DateTime gameTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["gameTime"]);


                events.Append("<div class='col-md-4'>");
                events.Append("<div class='well well-lg'>");
                events.Append("<form action='register/default.aspx' method='POST'>");
                events.Append("<h4>" + reportTime.DayOfWeek + " " + reportTime.Month + "/" + reportTime.Day + "/" + reportTime.Year + "</h4>");
                events.Append("<h5>" + reader["eventName"].ToString() + " " + reader["location"].ToString() + " " + reportTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "</h5>");

                events.Append(loadHelpers(reader["id"].ToString()));

                events.Append("<!--<span style='text-align:right; margin-top:20px;'><input type='submit' value='Edit' class='btn btn-info' /></span>-->");
                events.Append("</form>");
                events.Append("</div>");
                events.Append("</div>");
            }
            return events.ToString();
        }
        return "no info provided";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "ERROR" + e;
    }
}

public string loadHelpers(string id)
{

    var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM fundrasier_helpers WHERE eventID='"+ id + "'" , con2);
    con2.Open();
    if (cmd2.ToString() != "")
    {
        SqlDataReader reader2;
        StringBuilder helper = new StringBuilder();
        helper.Append("<ul>");
        try
        {
            reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader2.HasRows)
            {

                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    helper.Append("<li>" + reader2["firstName"] + " " + reader2["lastName"] + " " + reader2["phone"] + " " + reader2["shirtSize"] + "</li>");
                }
            }
            reader2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            helper.Append("<li>No volunteers have signed up " + e + "</li>");
        }
        helper.Append("</ul>");
        con2.Close();
        return helper.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "<ul><li>No volunteers have signed up</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first aspect of your stated problem is the select list. `Select *` will return all columns of all joined tables in the query for each joined row. So, each of your helpers will have the fundraising event information as part of its row data.

One side note for maintenance: `select *` is a bad habit for "production code", especially if you're getting fields out of the result set by index (which you are), because if you add a field to `fundraiser_youth`, all the indexes representing fields from `fundraiser_helpers` will no longer line up with the result set being returned, and your UI and any validation logic on this field data will break. I recommend strongly that you either specify the list of desired columns explicitly, get them out of `reader` using the column names instead of index positions, or both.

Since you're digesting the results programmatically in C#, the easiest solution to your stated problem is to first change your `ORDER BY` clause so that rows are sorted by `fundraiser_youth.id` before anything else. Then, get the event information once on the first row, generate your event header and the first volunteer row in HTML, remember that event ID, and check it against the ID of subsequent rows as you iterate through the reader generating the rest of the volunteer HTML rows. As long as the event IDs match, ignore the event fields and only extract/display the helper fields. When they differ, the event has changed and you need to re-retrieve the event information for the next sub-header.

Comment: do you have a quick example i can look at I'm not wrapping my head around where to place the check.   Thanks for your help